# pandas list manipulation and fill NA

Tags: python, pandas, function, filter

I am trying to use this function in order to extract the `AdjClose` value from a dataframe.

```
def get_sell_price(data):
    buy_date = get_buy_date(data)
    sell_date = get_sell_date(buy_date)
    l=[]
    for i in range(0,len(buy_date)):
        sell_price = data[(data.Date == sell_date[i])].AdjClose
        l.append(sell_price)
    return l
```

This returns the data:

```
[8180    110.459999
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17052    655.679993
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17452    968.099976
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17453    970.280029
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17454    965.719971
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17455    955.25
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17458    944.159973
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17462    950.690002
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17470    914.619995
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17497    951.640015
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17536    977.070007
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17537    966.580017
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 17538    964.0
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 18180    1335.209961
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 18181    1313.040039
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 18182    1285.550049
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 21116    1514.400024
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 21424    1300.680054
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 22006    1178.099976
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 22016    1196.47998
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 22017    1197.300049
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 22018    1210.650024
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 22537    1209.109985
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25106    2914.0
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25113    2901.610107
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25114    2885.570068
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25116    2885.570068
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25117    2884.429932
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25118    2880.340088
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25119    2785.679932
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25122    2767.129883
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25129    2767.780029
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25143    2723.060059
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25144    2723.060059
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25157    2736.27002
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25158    2736.27002
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25169    2737.800049
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25219    2670.709961
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, 25240    2707.879883
 Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64, Series([], Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64), Series([], Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64)]
```

I would preferably change this following line

```
sell_price = data[(data.Date == sell_date[i])].AdjClose
```

to

```
sell_price = data[(data.Date == sell_date[i])].AdjClose.values[0]
```

so that I would only get the value list without explanations attached in them.

However, the last 2 items in the list is empty, so when it tries to extract the value, it causes error. It is because 2 of the `sell_date` in the data frame is in 2020 thus it has no data to return, thus causes index error.

I tried to filter the `sell_date` < 2019-2-28 as that is the amount of data I have. But it does not work as this entire table needs to have 41 rows.

Is there any way I can return the values with 0 within that function using

```
sell_price = data[(data.Date == sell_date[i])].AdjClose.values[0]
```

I appreciate your experience and insights!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next` with `iter` for first value if exist, else default value (here `NaN`) is returned.

Better for select column with filter is use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
sell_price = next(iter(data.loc[(data.Date == sell_date[i]), 'AdjClose']), np.nan)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate your tip and the reference!